# PubSub Cloud Function updating the GKE deployed images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement where the images are been pushed from another provider (AWS) to GCP Container registry . Now i wanted the new pushed images to GKE. I am planning to use pub-sub with cloud function. But i am very new to this, can anyone help me to provide a reference, how cloud-function access gke cluster and update the nodes ?

Comment: What's your question? Is it about access to Kubernetes API to deploy a new pod? Or to get the event that a new version of a container has been pushed?

Comment: hi, how to access the kuberenets api's from a cloudfunction. any library do we have to call a k8 cluster from a cloudfunction ?

Comment: Libraries depends on your language. Basically, it's API and you can call the API that you want. Now, library should exists to wrap the API calls. WHat's your language?

Comment: java is my preferred language, do we have it ?

Answer (score 0):

Jithin I have some good news for you Google Cloud Pub/Sub supports java and
I have the following references for you, the first is to understand the event types and their structure with a java code example, the second is complete tutorial about all the steps to deploy the function, ther third is a tutorial about how to integrate microservices with pubsub and GKE and the last is a group of quickstarts to learn about PubSub, I hope are helpful for you.

1. [Cloud triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)
2. [Cloud tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#functions-deploy-command-java)
3. [Integrating microservices with pubsub and GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/integrating-microservices-with-pubsub)
4. [PubSub all quickstarts](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstarts)